# Popen returning nothing

Tags: python-3.x

Im trying to run a exe with some arguments within python using subprocesses `Popen` but the code is currently printing nothing as the output and a CMD window doesnt open when i run the file.

I know the command works as i manually paste it within CMD and it runs perfectly fine, what could i be doing wrong in my code?

```
import sys
import admin
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

Path_2to3 = sys.executable[:-11] + "Scripts"
cmdCommand = '''cd "{}" && 2to3.exe -w "C:/Users/Desktop/bulk_converter/tests/test2.py"'''.format(Path_2to3)
process = subprocess.Popen(cmdCommand, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = process.communicate()
print(output, error)
```

retured values from `print(output,error)`

```
b'' None
```

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Hi perhaps also specify `stderr` should be redirected to a pipe:

```
stderr=subprocess.PIPE
```

You may also be interested in passing a `timeout` parameter to `communicate`.